# What is Disk Image Mounter?

Tags: mount, iso, disk-image

I am using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit. On my hard disk when I select any ISO file and right-click on it, the menu list has 'Disk Image Mounter'. Please tell me full details about it, what is it and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Disk Image Mounter is a way to mount the contents of an ISO so they can be viewed. There are other ways to mount the ISO but without mounting it its contents are inaccessible.

[How to Easily Mount ISO Images In Ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/easily-mount-iso-images-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but the link that you have provided is completely superfluous:  There is no information there which is not in your answer!  You could point the OP to [http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html)

Comment: @CharlesGreen: You are not wrong, but since OP is a new user and seems to have happened across this option through the GUI as opposed to the command line, I felt it was best to keep it simple and to provide a link to a page that also used the graphical interface.